# Issue with CDT in eclipse

Tags: c++, pointers, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse for C++ program.

After building my code when I am running the code I am getting **name.exe has stopped working** error.
Same code is working fine here http://codepad.org/2c5xFbLM .

Please help me finding this issue.
Thanks in advance.
My code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    struct node * lc;
    struct node * rc;
    int data;
};

typedef struct node Node;

Node * getNewNode(int data){
    Node * node = NULL;

    node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node -> data = data;
    node -> lc = NULL;
    node -> rc = NULL;

    return node;
}

Node * buildBst(Node * root,int data){
    if(NULL == root){
        return getNewNode(data);
    }
    if(data > root -> data){
        root -> rc = buildBst(root->rc,data);
    }else{
        root -> lc = buildBst(root->lc,data);
    }
    return root;
}

void printInorder(Node * root){
    if(root != NULL){
        printInorder(root -> lc);
        cout << root -> data << " ";
        printInorder(root -> rc);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int arr [] = {2,3,4,1,5,9,0,3};
    Node * root = NULL;
    for(int i = 0;i < 6; ++i){
        root = buildBst(root,arr[i]);
    }
    printInorder(root);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Codeblocks with GCC/G++ compiles and runs it properly, are you setting any compiler flags?

Comment: No. I am not setting any compiler flags

Comment: Interesting, debug version is fine yet release is not. Although am curious why you are not using the `new` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using C++, use the `new` operator instead of `malloc`, the crash happened upon the 14th iteration at your call to malloc, or your 4th node creation, because of the additional padding with debugging, it allowed it in debug mode ( though technically UB otherwise ) and probably wrote through the guard bytes.

Likewise, it crashed on the malloc code because you were using `sizeof(node)` vs `sizeof(Node)`.

Comment: And now, to fix the misconception from this post: in environment with full working standard library, *almost* **never** use `new` - in proper modern C++ programming, dynamic memory allocation and deallocation is handled internally by standard library - either in containers or smart pointers. Don't recommend using `new`, seriously.

Comment: As per my usual motive, instead of trying to reinvent shantanu's wheel, I made the code s/he was using work as is. Which is exactly why I suggested using new (C++) vs malloc (C), but gave the method to keep malloc working as well. Likewise, there's more than one way to get to home base in the world of programming, I just left his/her path intact for the most part.